# Find all the values of $c$, if any, for which $f(f(x))=x$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> Extracted from The Eleventh W.J. BLUNDON Contest, Consider the function $f(x)=\frac{cx}{2x+3},x\ne-\frac{3}{2}$. Find all the values of $c$, if any, for which $f(f(x))=x$.

My attempt,

$$\frac{c(\frac{cx}{2x+3})}{\frac{2cx}{2x+3}+3}=x$$

$$\frac{c^2x}{2cx+3(2x+3)}=x$$

$$c^2x=2cx^2+3x(2x+3)$$

$$c^2x=2cx^2+6x^2+9x$$

By comparing the coefficients,

$$c^2=9 \space \text{and} \space 2c+6=0$$

So, $$c=-3$$

But the given answer is 3. Why? What's wrong with my solution?

Comment: The "answers at the back of the book" are not always correct.

Comment: The answer seems to be wrong if I didn't misinterpret the problem.

Comment: If you want to make sure -3 is answer but not 3, just Check these two numbers and see result....

Comment: $c=-3$ is the correct answer.

Comment: Is the question for which values of c is f (f (x)) *always* true for all x? Or for what values of c is f (f (x)) sometimes true for some x? If always, you are correct.  If sometimes you must solve for x in terms of c, when c != -3.

Comment: Oh, never mind.  It's clear in context they meant always.  But I think the book made a typo.  That's not uncommon.  The answer should be -3.

Comment: Btw, your solution was impressively methodical, neat and clean.  It was very nice to read.

Comment: @fleablood Thanks a lot. I doubt the my answer as the answer provided if from a popular maths journal. But it seems that, it's a typo.

Answer (score 3):

[Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-3(-3x%2F(2x%2B3))%2F(-6x%2F(2x%2B3)%2B3)) and I agree with you that $c=-3$ works.[image]